# Do beit dins have the right to disbar Jewish attorneys

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court, modern-times, authority

According to Halacha, does a beit din have the jurisdictional authority and right to disbar Jewish lawyers? Furthermore, do  they have the right to prevent  them from being lawyers in secular courts or only from not being valid lawyers amongst beit dins?

Comment: According to Halacha, what's a "lawyer"? And what is "disbar"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beis din does not use lawyers. The litigants don't make legal arguments. They testify, the judges ask them questions, and the judges decide how the law applies.

In some case the litigants can send a representative but the use of these is limited and frowned upon. A lawyer can also be used but only the litigants testimony is acceptable and too much coaching or leading is frowned upon.

There is no "license" for anyone to be a representative but a court can set up it's own rules of who they will accept. They could blacklist someone if they wanted to.

The RCA requires that the lawyers be real lawyers so the arbitration can be recognized by the secular courts. If the real lawyer is misbehaving the beit din can make a complaint to the bar association.

As to whether they can forbid a lawyer from working in secular court, the gemara has.many cases of non standard decrees. They could put the lawyer in cherem or have goons beat him up or kill him but their enforcement powers are very limited.

Read all about it:

https://www.sefaria.org/Gray_Matter_II,_Beit_Din,_The_Role_of_Lawyers_in_Beit_Din

Comment: Just a bit more: assuming you're talking about in the US today. Some batei din allow a litigant to hire a *to'ein*, kinda sorta like a lawyer; ideally they help the litigant sharpen and focus their argument. As you said, many Batei Din don't allow them at all. A Beis Din that sees a *to'ein* acting in an awful way (the kind of behavior that could get a lawyer disbarred) ... they can set the rules for their own Beis Din and not allow that *to'ein* back, I suppose (just as they could refuse all to'anim) ... but there's really nothing stopping the fellow from going to some other Beis Din.